# QTP DotNetFactory vs COM-Visible .NET Assemblies

Tags: .net, com, qtp

I'm just curious - QTP has the functionality to call .NET objects directly via the DotNetFactory object, see [this article from learnqtp.com](http://www.learnqtp.com/dotnetfactory-qtp-part1-basics/), but it can also call objects through COM (see [this post from Joe Colantonio](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/09/13/qtp-how-to-use-a-net-dll-in-quicktest-professionalfunctional-testing/)).  What would the advantage be in using one method over another? So far as I can tell, both methods have similar restrictions on the objects that can be called (no constructors with parameters, etc.), but I'm wondering about deeper details.

Thanks!

Comment: Erm, one lets you use .NET code, the other COM code.  Not the same thing.  Looks like it uses Reflection, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all one of your assumptions is wrong, `DotNetFactory` **does** support calling constructors with parameters (that's what the optional `args` parameter is for).

The `CreateObject` function is [built in for VBScript](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_createobject.asp), since QTP tests are written in VBScript this functionality comes for *free* and is not technically a QTP feature. The `DotNetFactory` *is* part of QTP and allows creating .NET objects even if they are not COM visible.

If you have a .NET object which is COM visible you can choose which method you're more comfortable with but if you have a COM object you must use `CreateObject` and if you have a non-COM visible object you must use `DotNetFactory`.